# How to ensure consistent spacing in creating number pyramid (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a number pyramid in python, and none of the solutions I've found on Stack Overflow are quite what I'm looking for. Here is the code I have so far:

```
for i in range(1, height+1):
    for j in range(1, height-i+1):
        if j > 9:
            print(len(str(j)) * " ", end=" ")
        else:
            print(" ", end=" ")
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(j, end=" ")
    for j in range(2, i + 1):
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

And here is the output:

```
                                 1 
                              2 1 2 
                           3 2 1 2 3 
                        4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
                     5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
                  6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 
                7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
              8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
            9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
          10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
        11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
      12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 
    13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 
  14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

From what I can see, the code works fine with heights <= 9, but once double digits come in, the alignment fails. I also need to ensure that the spacing between each number is consistent (ONE space in between each number), but the workarounds that I've looked at involve adding more than one space.

Please let me know if there is anything I should clarify, and thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Are you open to a solution which pads the single digit numbers with leading zeros?

Comment: Would it be possible to pad with leading spaces instead? If so, absolutely.

Comment: You have to pad so that one way or another, single digit and double digits take up the same amount of space.  There's no way around that.  I can only see putting an extra space or leading zeros.  Take your choice.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm just not quite sure how this padding would look syntactically. Would I put it in a format function, or is there another way to go about it?

Comment: zfill pads strings with zeros: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp

Comment: You can do `print(f'{j:{width}')` to specify "print `j`, but within a specific width, padded with spaces if `j` would be shorter"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string formatting to define a fixed width for a field, padded by either whitespace or zeroes.

```
field_len = len(str(height))
for i in range(1, height+1):
    for j in range(1, height-i+1):
        print(" " * field_len, end=" ")
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(f"{j:{field_len}}", end=" ")
    for j in range(2, i + 1):
        print(f"{j:{field_len}}", end=" ")
    print()
```

which produces

```
                                           1 
                                        2  1  2 
                                     3  2  1  2  3 
                                  4  3  2  1  2  3  4 
                               5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5 
                            6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6 
                         7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
                      8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
                   9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
               10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
            11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
         12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
      13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 
   14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 
15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

and which will auto-adjust the spacing depending on if the number of digits change.

This keeps the slope of the pyramid the same, though the alignment appears to get more sparse with interior numbers, as they're padded into two spaces.

A solution to that is just to use the width of the current number as the number of spaces - which we can do by changing the arguments to `range()` where it prints the spaces, to actually count down from the height.

```
for i in range(1, height+1):
    for j in range(i, height):
        print(" " * len(str(j + 1)), end=" ")
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(j, end=" ")
    for j in range(2, i + 1):
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

This produces a pyramid with uneven slopes but even spacing.

```
                                  1 
                                2 1 2 
                              3 2 1 2 3 
                            4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
                          5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
                        6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 
                      7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
                    8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
                  9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
               10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
            11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
         12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 
      13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 
   14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 2):

just for completeness I will provide another approach to this problem.
the main idea is to keep track of the length of the current line and use `rjust` to pad with whatever delimeter you wish (I chose the default whitespace)

```
height = 16
max_line_len = len(' '.join([str(i) for i in range(height,0,-1)] + [str(i) for i in range(2,height+1)]))
half_max_line_len = int((max_line_len+1)/2)
list_of_nums = [str(1)]
print('creating pyramid...')
for num in range(1, height+1):
    print(' '.join(list_of_nums).rjust(half_max_line_len))
    list_of_nums = [str(num+1)] + list_of_nums + [str(num+1)]
    half_max_line_len += len(str(num+1))+1
```

output:

```
creating pyramid...
                                     1
                                   2 1 2
                                 3 2 1 2 3
                               4 3 2 1 2 3 4
                             5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
                           6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
                         7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                       8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
                     9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
                  10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
               11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
            12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
         13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
      14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
   15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```